# An image requires an environment variable to run, how to pass variable on Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a Dockerfile based on the realm/realm-object-server image.
To create a container with that image, I have to run the command:

> $ docker run -p 9080:9080 -e ROS_TOS_EMAIL_ADDRESS="your-email-address" 
>   realm/realm-object-server

providing an email.

My Dockerfile starts:

> FROM realm/realm-object-server:latest

how can I pass the ROS_TOS_EMAIL_ADDRESS environment variable to the FROM image? Otherwise it gives me an error later when executing the realm-object-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to pass env variables into docker.

- Use ENV in Dockerfile. Refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)
- Use -env-file option in `docker run` command. Refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables).
- Use -e option in `docker run` command. Refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)
- Use `environment` block in docker-compose

Based on your question, first one is good enough.

Comment: Thanks anyway :p I was stuck but lucked out onto the answer.

Comment: Is there any way to apply the env variables for every image build? For example, if I build the image behind corporate proxy, I have to specify the proxy env variables. But if I build the same image somewhere else, I should not add the env variables.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, nevermind.

An ENV ROS_TOS_EMAIL_ADDRESS="email-goes-here" after FROM works. 
I thought it had to be set before FROM and only ARG was possible for that, which did not set an environment variable just a variable for the Dockerfile context.

Now it works.